# Identify the item clicked on ListActivity method onListItemClick

Tags: android, listactivity, listitem

I'm developing an Android application.

I have several objects loaded on a `ListActivity`. I want to know the item clicked on event `onListItemClick`.

I see method `onListItemClick` has a parameter called id. How can I setup this id?

My objects are identified by an ID, how can I add this ID to listItem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is the source of your list data?  If you are using a cursor - then the id passed in `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` will automatically be the id of the cursor row.

Comment: I'm not using a cursor. I'm using a String array.

Comment: Then assuming your array contains the ID in one of its indexis, access the array using the position variable.  i.e.  myArray[position][0] (if your ID is @ index 0 of the array)

Comment: Do you see what I mean?  The source data must have your objects ID present to begin with, whether it be a String[] or ArrayList, or cursor or any other source.

Comment: It can be a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

if SectionObj is your object that you want to access later, set that in the adapter when you set the source.

```
ArrayList<SectionObj> li

ArrayAdapter<SectionObj> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<SectionObj>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, li);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

then in ur listener method..

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

SectionObj o=(SectionObj)getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Use the following;

```
listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Where listView is the name of your list view.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. For example, I put object with id = 1 on position 12. I don't want to know the position, I want to know the id from the object on an specific position.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the id in your ArrayAdapter  view. 
Checkout the following pages then you should find the solution.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)

http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications